# WPF Window border thickness and Visual Studio Version

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I was attempting to rewrite a WPF program previously written in Visual Studio 2010 in Visual Studio 2013 when I noticed a major difference in the thickness of the window border between the two versions of Visual Studio.

[image: The thickness of WPF window border made by Visual Studio 2013 (Right) is significantly thinner than that made by Visual Studio 2010 (Left)]

As seen from the picture above, the border thickness of the window written using Visual Studio 2013 is significantly much thinner than that written using Visual Studio 2010, but I was using the exact same code! Any one has an idea why is this so, and how could I increase the border thickness back to the original?

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't have any role in it. Have you changed application target framework while migrating?

Comment: I have set them to default. The one using VS2010 is set to .NET Framework 3.5 while the one using VS2013 is set to .NET Framework 4.5.1

Comment: But even if I changed the target framework, the result is still the same. And it only happens for this program. Any other WPF programs are fine.

Comment: Just noticed the same thing on our machines.  We even tested all the frameworks from 3.5 up on both.  Interestingly, `SystemParameters.BorderWidth` returns 5.0 on VS2010 but only1.0 on VS2013 regardless of the framework, which matches what you're seeing visually.